# Check Dataflow errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to implement a data pipeline where I am trying insert a json in PubSub from there via DataFlow into BQ. I am using the template to transfer data from PubSub to BQ.  My DataFlow is failing. It is going in the error flow. But I don't see where to get more details on the error. Eg, is it failing due to bad encoding of the data in pubsub, failing because of schema mismatch etc. etc.? Where can I find these details? I am checking Stackdriver error and logs but not able to locate where to find further details.

To add to that, I can see this error:

> resource.type="dataflow_step"
>   resource.labels.job_id="2018-07-17_20_36_16-6729875790634111180"
>   logName="projects/camel-154800/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker"
>   timestamp >= "2018-07-18T03:36:17Z" severity>="INFO"
>   resource.labels.step_id=("WriteFailedRecords/FailedRecordToTableRow"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/PrepareWrite/ParDo(Anonymous)"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/CreateTables/ParDo(CreateTables)"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/ShardTableWrites"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/TagWithUniqueIds"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/Reshuffle/Window.Into()/Window.Assign"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/Reshuffle/GroupByKey"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/Reshuffle/ExpandIterable"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/GlobalWindow/Window.Assign"
>   OR
>   "WriteFailedRecords/WriteFailedRecordsToBigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/StreamingWrite")

It tells me it failed, but I have no clue why it failed?  Was there schema mismatch or data type problems or wrong encoding or what? How to debug?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406301/dataflow-failing-to-push-messages-to-bigquery-from-pubsub ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dataflow failing to push messages to BigQuery from PubSub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406301/dataflow-failing-to-push-messages-to-bigquery-from-pubsub)